# The disk \\.\physicaldrive1 was attached from WSL2, but failed to mount (error code: -22)

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Environment:
Build: 21343
Ubuntu 20.04
WSL2

Currently attempting to mount an ext4 drive via WSL2 and keep receiving error:

```
The disk \\.\physicaldrive1 was attached from WSL2, but failed to mount (error code: -22)
```

While running the following command:
`wsl --mount \\.\physicaldrive1`

Not sure what other information is needed, fairly new to linux and mounting drives.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. no one wants help here ?

Comment: Hey sorry i just saw this. did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

add the partition on the drive you want to mount what ever number it may be eg.

```
wsl --mount \\.\physicaldrive1 --partition 1
```